# Cannot create file with font(non unicode) in android lollipop

Tags: android, csv, fonts

I created new file **.csv** in my android storage programmatically. It got created with **en** font. But I cannot create it with Myanmar Font that is not unicode. Is there anyway to create? Normally, with that font, file name shows as **???.csv**. But programmatically, I could not create.

Comment: I don't catch you... a CSV is just a **plain text** file. It has no **font** definition. Maybe you mean the **encoding**?

Comment: If file name includes some character of that font, cannot create.

Comment: If your custom font doesn't support Unicode... change that font to one which does.

Comment: Sorry I don't know that is not font. Thanks for your comment. I will find more.

Comment: currently I request to add english name in api. But that's is not the good way I think. Thanks again.

Comment: I cannot change that font, in Myanmar we use two fonts widely. That's why

Comment: Well, I really suspect that the fonts you use really ARE Unicode fonts. So, save using the UTF-8 encoding. There's a difference between Windows and Android standard character encoding (I suspect you are using Windows).

Comment: Thanks. I m trying to create file programmatically in android. I m reading encoding as u suggest.